# Apache Clean-Urls with MultiViews enabled

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to allow Clean-Urls, having MultiViews enabled.

All the pages I have, are in the root folder itself.

I am trying to achieve the following :

```
(current-status -> what I am trying to achieve)

 1. foo.com/services.php -> foo.com/services
 2. foo.com/services == foo.com/services/
 3. foo.com/services.php/second-level/ == foo.com/services/second-level
```

The `services` is **not**  a folder, I explode `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` and get the second-level path data.

I have already achieved the first one, but it fails when I enable `MultiViews`, using a `.htaccess` file and writing a rewrite.

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

(Which would obviously fail, since it would change the request to services/second-level.php).
I know I can write multiple rewrites in the `.htaccess`, and conditionally redirect.

But the strange fact is that on the live environment (shared hosting), it is working, **without** any `.htaccess` file in the root folder. Since it is a shared hosting, I cannot read the configuration file.

Any ideas on what configuration should I change (in `apache.conf` or `*.conf`) to achieve the above?

If it matters, I'm using `Apache/2.2.22`, and this problem started happening after the update.

Comment: I don't think you want this: `foo.com/services.php -> foo.com/services` but this: `foo.com/services -> foo.com/services.php`. It doesn't make much sense to show in the browser's address an "ugly" URL where the resource is shown `(foo.com/services.php)` while hiding the "pretty" one `foo.com/services`, except when there are very special reasons. ¿Are there?

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA : I want Clean URL's itself. Just updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve it.

This works, removing the `.htaccess` file altogether, and changing the `Virtual Directory` to keep the following settings :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin my-email-id
    ServerName foo.bar
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/foo/

    <Directory /var/www/sites/foo/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Indexes
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This helps me get all the pages to work, exactly as they were working on the server, without any of the Rewrite Conditions.

Comment: Using the MultiViews approach, I often see see error "no acceptable variant" in Apache's error log. Is this also the case for you?

Comment: I was using "+MultiViews" with no luck. Adding "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php" made the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: This approach is broken. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16357933/1709587 for the problem it causes, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24598848/1709587 for a breakdown of why and how to fix it (which explicitly references this answer).

Answer (score 1):

While MultiViews can be used for this, *don't* add an arbitrary MIME type to PHP files to get them to be served by MultiViews, like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14306831/1709587) and many other sources on the internet suggest:

```
# Bad code - don't do this!
Options +MultiViews
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

This hack, which I explain in detail at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24598848/1709587, appears to work, but is actually broken; it will fail whenever the server receives a request with an `Accept` header that does not include `*/*`.

Instead, the clean solution is to use the [`MultiviewsMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#multiviewsmatch) directive to tell Apache that it's valid to serve `.php` files regardless of the `Accept` and `Accept-Language` headers of the request:

```
# Good code - use this instead!
Options +MultiViews
<Files "*.php">
    MultiviewsMatch Any
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean URLs without .php extensions and without using [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html).

A flexible Web environment with virtual subdomain support using [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_userdir.html) and [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Allows following url layout

- /var/www/sites/www/services.php

  - `http://foo.bar/services.php/second-level/`
  - `http://foo.bar/services/second-level/`
  - `http://www.foo.bar/services/second-level/`
  - `http://127.0.0.1/services/second-level/`
- /var/www/sites/www/admin/login.php

  - `http://foo.bar/admin/login.php/foo`
  - `http://foo.bar/admin/login/foo`
  - `http://www.foo.bar/admin/login/foo`

Note with or without prepending www. is equal because www. is obsolete today...
But now you can host virtual subdomains too simply by adding a folder in `/var/www/sites/` (remember DNS)

- /var/www/sites/images/imgpass.php

  - `http://images.foo.bar/imgpass.php/photo.jpg`
  - `http://images.foo.bar/imgpass/photo.jpg`
  - `http://www.images.foo.bar/imgpass/photo.jpg`
  - `http://127.0.0.1/~images/imgpass/photo.jpg`

...and so on but skips if /var/www/sites/images/imgpass itself exists.

I am using a multi-user environment where every user has its own webroot and subdomain.

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/foo.bar.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin my-email-id
  ServerName foo.bar
  ServerAlias 127.0.0.1 *.foo.bar

  # The default web-root if no subdomain is given
  DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/www/

  UserDir /var/www/sites/*
  <Directory /var/www/sites/*>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
            Options -MultiViews -Indexes

            # MultiViews workaround with 1 level subdir support
            RewriteEngine On

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(\/var\/www\/sites\/.+(\/[^\/]+){2}).*
            RewriteCond %1.php -f
            RewriteRule ^\/var\/www\/sites\/(.+)((?:\/[^\/]+){2})(.*) /~$1$2.php$3 [L]

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(\/var\/www\/sites\/.+(\/[^\/]+){1}).*
            RewriteCond %1.php -f
            RewriteRule ^\/var\/www\/sites\/(.+)((?:\/[^\/]+){1})(.*) /~$1$2.php$3 [L]
   </Directory>

   # Force all requests in background to UserDir compatible requests
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteMap      lc                      int:tolower

   RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !^/~
   RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}            ^(www\.)?(.+)\.foo\.bar$
   RewriteRule     /(.*)                   /~${lc:%2}/$1                   [PT,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

This code is not testet because my file system structure differs completely from the initial example.
So I converted my configuration on the fly to fit to this example structure.

Note the configuration is incomplete. You need to tune it yourself for Your needs.