# .htaccess to remove extention doesn't work

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http, url

I have the following problem:

I want to remove **.php** and **.html extention** from **url of my website**.

The url is `localhost/MySiteDir/MySitePage.php` and I want to obtain `localhost/MySiteDir/MySitePage`.

I am following this:

https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

& this

[How to remove file extension from website address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address) guides.

So I created a `.htaccess` file on my `MySiteDir` and i put this code on this file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

I have changed etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf file adding

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
  </Directory>
```

in this way

```
<VirtualHost *:80>



<Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
  </Directory>

    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and if in .htaccess i put

```
RewriteEngine on                          # enable url rewriting
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d       # rewrite if the requested url is not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f   # rewrite if the php file exists
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]             # add .php to the url

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f  # rewrite if the html file exists
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

when i try to access to my website i receive a 500 ERROR.

Comment: What happens when you try to access `localhost/MySiteDir/MySitePage`? Do you get a 404 or does _"doesn't work"_ mean something else? Does it still work to access `localhost/MySiteDir/MySitePage.php`?

Comment: do you want to force a redirect to the url without extension or just be able to access the page without the extension ?

Comment: I get 404, and than, if i try localhost/MySiteDir/MySitePage.php, it works! Can this issue be caused by permissions??

Comment: i want to delete .php and .html from all urls of my web app

Comment: there is a difference between *"allow access to pages without extension"* and *"redirect the user to a page without extension"* in the first case, if the user goes to `example.com/page` or `example.com/page.php` the page will be displayed the same and for the other case, if the user goes to `example.com/page.php` he will be redirected to `example.com/page`

Comment: Yes, i want the first case

Comment: You dont need all that code. just put the following line to your .htaccess **Options +Multiviews**

Comment: Multiview is ok only if you are sure that you will never have a folder named the same as a file. if you have a folder `config` and a file `config.php` apache will always serve the php file

Comment: also, multiview can cause some `406 Not acceptable` errors because the rewriting relies on the accept header of the request. If the request sends `accept text/html` apache will not serve a php file since it is a `application/x-httpd-php` file (see : http://stackoverflow.com/q/16357933/3992945)

Comment: see my edit on the answer, i made a mistake : line comments must be on a "comment only" line and not after a directive

Answer (score 1):

Replace below code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

[Remove .php extensions with .htaccess without breaking DirectoryIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635524/remove-php-extensions-with-htaccess-without-breaking-directoryindex)

Comment: I changed the .htaccess file with your code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe ca be because of permission of MySiteDir directory?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be sure that the rewrite module is installed and enabled ([see this question](https://superuser.com/questions/284898/how-to-check-which-apache-modules-are-enabled-installed))

Once the rewrite module is enabled, make sure the apache config allows htaccess files ([see the doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride))

Then, you will need two rules for your rewrites one for PHP, the other for html :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: if i do apache2ctl -M

Comment: i receive a list of loaded modules

Comment: *you should not put the output of a command in the comments*, just look if the rewrite module is shown in the list of modules. If it is not, then install and enable it first

Comment: i have installed and then received "rewrite_module (shared)" but it doesn't work the same

Comment: does apache config allow htaccess rules ? you should have `AllowOverride All` in the config file of your vhost located in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` for debian based OS

Comment: AllowOverride All is ok... if i put your code on .htaccess i receive a 500 error

Comment: my bad, line comments are not allowed in htaccess files, i edit the answer

Comment: ok i have copy the new code (above these comments) but, if i try without extention in the url i receive a 404